# No se muestra mi ListView en Widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Lo primero decir que es la primera vez que hago un `Widget` seguramente este realizando mal el proceso, por eso pido ayuda, una vez dicho esto, voy con mi problema.

En mi clase principal, `MainActivity` tengo un `ListView` que voy rellenando con mi `Sqlite` y todo funciona perfectamente, pero quiero hacer un `Widget` con esa `ListView` pero mi `Widget` no muestra nada, como si el `layout` estuviese vacío.

En `MainActivity` lo tengo así y funciona perfectamente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseHandler baseDatos;
    private ImagenAdapter cursorAdapter;
    private ListView listViewPersonas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listViewPersonas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPersonas);

        // Se recuperan todas las personas de la base de datos
        recuperarTodasPersonas();
    }

    private void recuperarTodasPersonas() {
        try{
            baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            // Devuelve todas las personas en el objeto Cursor.
            Cursor cursor = baseDatos.obtenerTodasPersonas();
            String[] from = new String[]{
                    "nombre",
                    "nombre1",
                    "nombre2",
                    "nombre3",
                    "nombre4",
                    "ruta_imagen"
            };
            int[] to = new int[]{
                    R.id.persona_nombre,
                    R.id.persona_nombre1,
                    R.id.persona_nombre2,
                    R.id.persona_nombre3,
                    R.id.persona_nombre4,
                    R.id.foto_gallery,
            };
            cursorAdapter = new ImagenAdapter(this, cursor, from, to);
            listViewPersonas.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        }finally{
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }
}
```

Y así lo he realizado en mi `AppWidgetProvider`:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private DatabaseHandler baseDatos;
    private ImagenAdapter cursorAdapter;
    private static Context mContext;
    private ListView listViewPersonas;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        // mi listview

        RemoteViews remoteViews1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.id.listViewPersonas);

        // Se recuperan todas las personas de la base de datos

        recuperarTodasPersonas();

        // abre MainActivity al hacer clic en el Widget

        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_principal, configPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }

    private void recuperarTodasPersonas() {
        try {
            baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
            // Devuelve todas las personas en el objeto Cursor.
            Cursor cursor = baseDatos.obtenerTodasPersonas();
            String[] from = new String[]{
                    "nombre",
                    "nombre1",
                    "nombre2",
                    "nombre3",
                    "nombre4",
                    "ruta_imagen"
            };
            int[] to = new int[]{
                    R.id.persona_nombre,
                    R.id.persona_nombre1,
                    R.id.persona_nombre2,
                    R.id.persona_nombre3,
                    R.id.persona_nombre4,
                    R.id.foto_gallery,
            };
            cursorAdapter = new ImagenAdapter(mContext, cursor, from, to);
            listViewPersonas.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        } finally {
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest`

```
...

  <receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

...
```

`xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Pero como he dicho arriba, en mi `Widget` no hay ni rastro del `ListView` y no sé a que se puede deber.

¿Alguien que me pueda decir qué hago mal y como solucionarlo?

Gracias!

Comment: En el listView que quieres utilizar, quieres mostrar 6 datos, 5 String y uno de imagen verdad ?

Comment: Sí, como muestro en el código @Sam.Gold

Comment: Vale entendido, y el adaptador del listView donde muestras la información donde le tienes ? Necesitas un adaptador y un layout con los datos ***(nombre,nombre1,nombre2,nombre3,nombre4,ruta_imagen)***, ese layout es cada fila de tu listView.

Comment: Sí, todo eso está correctamente, ya que en `MainActivity` veo la `ListView` perfecta, pero lo que no consigo es verla en mi `Widget` @Sam.Gold

Comment: Si, lo he añadido a la pregunta para que lo puedas ver @Sam.Gold

Comment: Dime si te funciona con el código que te he dejado

Answer (score 0):

Mira a ver si te funciona esto :

Te adjunto el código del AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".WidgetService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

Te adjunto un link a un proyecto en GitHub de un listView en un Widget, espero que te sirva.

Link:
[Proyecto ListView + Widget](https://github.com/laaptu/appwidget-listview/tree/appwidget-listview1)

Comment: No me ha funcionado, además **Android Studio** me marca lo siguiente en esa línea, ".WidgetProvider is not assignable to ´android.app.Service´ @Sam.Gold

Comment: Vale copia el codigo que te paso a ver, acuérdate de cambiar el android:resource, por como se llame el tuyo

Comment: Lo que me comentas de `AndroidManifest` es como ya lo tengo, no? Gracias por el proyecto, lo miraré y comento, gracias! @Sam.Gold

Comment: Perdona, me habia comido código al editar la respuesta